# Converting a nested for loop to declarative in c#

Tags: c#, linq

How would convert a nested for loop to declarative style?

Sample code:

```
List<String> words = new List<String>();
Books.ForEach(book => book.ForEach(page => 
                                  page.ForEach(line =>words.Add(CreateWord(book, page, line)))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to improve readability, then you could approach step-by-step. First expand each `book` entry into a sequence of (book, page) pairs. Then each pair convert to a triplet (book, page, line) and convert that to strings using the `CreateWords` method.

Code is telling more than words, and this is how it looks:

```
List<string> words = Books
    .SelectMany(book => book.Pages.Select(page => new
        {
            Book = book,
            Page = page
        }))
    .SelectMany(pair => pair.Page.Lines.SelectMany(line =>
        new CreateWords(book, page, line));
```

This might not be the most readable piece of LINQ code. But it often goes like that. LINQ tends to produce compact but ugly mapping code.

On a related note, I wonder what is the purpose of `CreateWords` method? If it only returns a sequence of strings, then entire adventure with book, page and line is not required. If I'm right, you might change `CreateWords` to only receive a single string representing the line - it does not require book or page objects at all. In that case, query would be simplified:

```
List<string> words = Books
    .SelectMany(book => book.Pages)
    .SelectMany(page => page.Lines)
    .SelectMany(line => CreateWords(line));
```

Comment: You don't need the anonymous type. With doing selects inside of eachother you have full access to the selects all the way up.

Comment: While that explains using anonymous types and might be (for better or worse) a bit more verbose, Rob's original SelectMany() calls were nested and therefor could reference book and page without the wrapping objects just fine. I'd probably go for the more succinct nested version, but do think that you explain the concept clearly.

Comment: @Dispersia I did that to improve readability. Nested `Selects` are very hard to follow. In this example, we would have to nest three levels deep, and that is really too much to understand. But I agree that the solution would produce the same output.

Comment: @Zoran I was trying to replicate a code that I have, in this case consider CreateWord to create an anagram or some such thing (a factory to create word) and add it to the list. I corrected the code it's not CreateWords it is CreateWord. Page and Book, are required in the actual code, since the Word is actual an assimilation of information from Book and Page.

Comment: In that case the first listing should produce correct output.